# LimeSurvey: Skip "The following surveys are available" Page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, limesurvey

I have recently installed the latest LimeSurvey, and while it has many features I like, I only really intend on having one survey available at a survey.example.com subdomain.

I want to skip the page that states "The following surveys are available:" which is the `"survey.example.com/index.php"`. and go straight to the survey, which is `"survey.example.com/index.php/311746?lang=en"`

I tried setting a DirectoryIndex in .htaccess but that didn't do anything

`DirectoryIndex index.php/311746?lang=en`

I've tried playing with mod_rewrite, but LimeSurvey itself already has conditions set up, so whatever I tend to do breaks theirs (likely since they're already rewriting index.php).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

I was going to try a redirect, but the index.php is more than just the index, so I don't want to change that too much.

I've tried searching around but I haven't had much luck.

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: I don't really have anything - I couldn't get mod_rewrite working with their existing conditions pre-built into the app itself, and the index.php isn't an actual page (it's all PHP code, no HTML) so I didn't think it was wise to put a redirect in there. I'm looking for other suggestions to achieve the same goal that don't involve mod_rewrite or an index.php redirect

Comment: I've added what I've got to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then why not just rewrite the main rule of the survey. Instead of rewriting it to the main index.php which you don't want to do, write it directly to the survey you want. You should be able to use this in your htaccess to go directly to the survey.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to the survey
RewriteRule . index.php/311746?lang=en [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Let me know if this solves your issue

Comment: Thanks Jack! That's the first one I've tried that doesn't completely break it (all my attempts seemed to try to load directly from the /var/www path as opposed to the URL itself), and I can still complete the surveys like that, but unfortunately it's still placing me on that silly landing page (so it's re-writing a portion of it still but not adding the number or lang portion). It sounds like your idea is the best one though and it feels like we're on the right track. I am restarting apache after making these changes, but nothing in the logs. I will try turning verbosity up and testing as well

Comment: Does going straight to this `survey.example.com/index.php/311746?lang=en` work? There really shouldn't be any reason why that doesn't work. It should be the same thing as you going directly to it in the browser. is that all the rules in the .htaccess?

Comment: It does - and that's what I thought as well (I had a similar setup to what you had as my first test, but I definitely didn't have the [R=301,L] portion so I was hoping I just missed that) - for arguments sake I even tried deleting the old and creating a new .htaccess direct copy and paste from what you had and still no dice. I feel like mod_rewrite is off, but it's working elsewhere and I can see it's enabled in phpinfo / httpd.conf - it's got me stumped!

Comment: Clear your browser cache or try in a different browser that might not have seen the new rules and then use the rules I put above. Chrome and other browsers have a bad habit  of caching things as well and not updating.